# How to query various models with many-to-many through relation in shopping cart (Django)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cart

I built a shopping cart that uses a CartItem model as a many-to-many through relation and which queries currently the Product model.

However, I want to not only query the Product model but around 5 other models as well where other types of Products are stored (I needed to do so because of a bulk csv upload).

My understanding is that the only way to relate differente models for something like that might be through the content types framework which would allow me to sort of "tag" the different Products.

Is there an other way to maybe create one joint/summary model which I eventually could query as "one" model. Or how is something like that possible?

Thanks a lot! Below my code:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey("Cart")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=CartItem)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a raw query, with a raw query you can do joins or apply direct SQL code to database. The result will be a cursor which you can transform to a dictionary or another structure.

This topis : [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/sql/) talks about raw query's and methods to transform data.

Hope will help you!

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed helpful. However, what do you think about a foreign key relation and a new model since these Product Categories are quite stable and won't be changed any time soon.